# C program Output confusing (pointer)

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int *ptr = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        *(ptr + i) = i;

    printf("%d ", *ptr++);//prin1
    printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);//print2
    printf("%d ", *ptr);//print3
    printf("%d ", *++ptr);//print4
    printf("%d ", ++*ptr);//print5
}
```

i am getting

```
0 1 2 2 3
```

as output.

I am not able to understand why "print4" is printing 2 it should print 3 as pointer *++ptr will be treated as *(++ptr) i.e pointer will be incremented first

Comment: In C there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: If you ever work on a project with someone else, do them a favor and never write code like this.

Comment: As haccks points out, some of your code is incrementing the values at the pointer location, other bits of your code is incrementing the pointer itself.

Comment: Please remove all casts where you don't know **exactly** what you are doing and can explain why the cast is **neccessary** for correct working. Never muzzle the compiler, instead ask it to speak up: Use `-Wall -Wextra`, and handle all warnings appropriately. (You need to add `#include <stdlib.h>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, it is better to not cast the result of `malloc()`.  Doing so can hide bugs that the compiler would be able to warn you about, and the bugs in the worst case can cause your program to crash.

```
    int *ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

`ptr` now points to memory for 5 `int`s, and you initialize them with sequential values in your loop. At then end of the loop, the situation can be visualized like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+
   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+
     ^
    ptr
```

Now, we can draw a picture to correspond to each line of code.

```
printf("%d ", *ptr++);//prin1       +---+---+---+---+---+
                                    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                                    +---+---+---+---+---+
                                          ^
                                         ptr
```

Since post increment is used, `0` is printed, and `ptr` is incremented.

```
printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);//print2    +---+---+---+---+---+
                                    | 0 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                                    +---+---+---+---+---+
                                          ^
                                         ptr
```

The dereferenced value `1` is printed, and then post-incremented, so it becomes `2`. `ptr` did not move.

```
printf("%d ", *ptr);//print3        +---+---+---+---+---+
                                    | 0 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                                    +---+---+---+---+---+
                                          ^
                                         ptr
```

Now, the dereferenced value `2` is printed, and nothing was changed.

```
printf("%d ", *++ptr);//print4      +---+---+---+---+---+
                                    | 0 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                                    +---+---+---+---+---+
                                              ^
                                             ptr
```

The pre-increment on `ptr` moves it to the next element, and the dereferenced value `2` is printed.

```
printf("%d ", ++*ptr);//print5      +---+---+---+---+---+
                                    | 0 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
                                    +---+---+---+---+---+
                                              ^
                                             ptr
```

The dereferenced value `2` is pre-incremented, so the value `3` is printed.

Answer (score 5):

`*ptr++`    --> Print `0`, increment `ptr` by `1`.
`(*ptr)++`  --> Print `1`, increment `1` to `2`.
`*ptr`      --> Print the incremented value stored, i.e `2`.
`*++ptr`    --> Increment the `ptr` by `1` and then print the value pointed by `ptr`, which is `2`.
`++*ptr`    --> Increment the value , i.e `2`, pointed by `ptr` and then print it, i.e `3`.

Comment: in print3 i am using pre increment so it should print 3

Comment: That preincrement will modify `ptr` by `1` not the content of `ptr` points to. (I hope you talked about print4).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you didn't increase at print3.

Comment: Not enough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not understanding where ptr is pointing to in the flow... does the below  extra comments clear it up?

```
printf("%d ", *ptr++);  // ptr now point to ptr[1] which is initialized to 1
printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);// update ptr[1] to 1+1 = 2
printf("%d ", *ptr);    //  printing the value pf ptr[1]
printf("%d ", *++ptr);  // incrementing ptr, to pointing to ptr[2] which 
                        // is initialized to 2....
printf("%d ", ++*ptr);  // incrementing the value of ptr[2] to (2+1) = 3
```